# Can I set up custom warnings in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, warnings, customization

So, I may sound crazy when I say that I want *more* warnings in my Java code, but hear me out. I'm transitioning to better coding practices, and want the IDE to help. In my older days, I made a library in packages like `bht.tools`, but now am moving to `org.bh.tools`. To do this, I'm moving the classes slowly and one-by-one, so that I can also go over their code to make sure best practices are being used there too. This has the added benefit of knowing that any class I import from the new packages has recently been reviewed to be more robust and efficient.

In short, **I want NetBeans to show a warning wherever I'm using `bht.`, whether it be in imports, fully-qualified names, etc.. Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Netbeans Java Hint Module. There is a nice tutorial [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-java-hint.html).

You probably need do define a [TriggerPattern](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-spi-java-hints/org/netbeans/spi/java/hints/TriggerPattern.html):

> Find parts of the source code that satisfy the given pattern, and invoke the method that is annotated with this annotation. The method must be public static, the return type must either be assignable to ErrorDescription or to Iterable. Its sole parameter must be HintContext.

and also a [JavaFix](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-spi-java-hints/org/netbeans/spi/java/hints/JavaFix.html)

> A base class for fixes that modify Java source code. Using this class as a base class makes creating the fix somewhat simpler, but also supports running the hint in the Inspect&Transform dialog. The fix can be converted to Fix by means of the toEditorFix() method.

Read the [official tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-java-hint.html) and the [org.netbeans.spi.java.hints documentation](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-spi-java-hints/overview-summary.html#overview_description) for full details.